# 0190 critical low battery error only on boot lenovo x 1 carbon gen 7

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, battery, lenovo-laptop

I replaced my x1 carbon battery with a new one. The battery itself seems to be okay. However, it isn't a Lenovo original (I can't find any). On boot, if I don't have a charging cable plugged in, it won't boot and states "0190 critical low battery error" even though it works perfectly fine in Windows when unplugged. Also, the battery voltage at 100% is around 16.01v. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the battery I got was "15.4V 51Wh battery for Lenovo ThinkPad X1 CARBON 7TH GEN-20QD"
from lenovobatt.

Answer (score 0):

I have such a machine and I used a certified Lenovo dealer to replace the battery and it works fine.

Lenovobatt is not a certified replacement source so far as I can see.

Accordingly, I suggest returning the battery for a refund and then get a battery from a certified source.